# Access image urls from Django ForeignKey relationship

Tags: django, image, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I currently have a model defined the same way as this one:

```
class Object(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class ObjectImage(models.Model):
    object = models.ForeignKey('Object', related_name='images')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='./objects')
```

I am trying to access the urls of all the images for each object so that they can be displayed in a template. I tried putting the objects in a list and then accessing list[0].images and that returns "ProjectName.ObjectImage.None".

Does anyone know how to access the urls of the images saved for each instance of the Object class? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to provide Object to your template to access ObjectImages. They will be available this way:

```
all_objects = Object.objects.all()
context = {'all_objects': all_objects}
render(render, your_template.html, context)
```

And in your template, like this:

```
{% for each_object in all_objects %}

{% for each_image in each_object.objectimage_set.all %}

{{ each_image.image }}

{% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried that, but it didn't work. So I put this in the view: print a.objectimage_set.all() after setting a equal to an object that has images, and I get the error "'Object' object has no attribute 'objectimage_set'. I know there are images associated with the object, because when I include: print Object.images.all(), I get three instances of the ObjectImage.

Comment: @tawalker ok, I thought you wanted it in your template. To get it in your view you can simply call ObjectImage.objects.all() and you'll have all your objectimages. After that it depends what you want to do with them

Comment: I did want it in my view. I was just putting those statements in to see why it wasn't working. I finally figured it out though. I had to take out related_name='images' from the foreignkey field. Once I did that, I used your original answer and it worked perfectly. Thanks!